# How to check current build variant in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

In Android project gradle.build file looks like below:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
    }

    release {           
        minifyEnabled true
     }

    emulator{
    }

}
```

And then I would like to do something depends what kind of build was executed:

```
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

            variant.getAssembleProvider().configure() {
    //For example:
    if(buildType == 'release'){
          //do something
      }
   }
 }
```

How can I check current **Build Variant**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `variant.name`, or `"${variant.name}"` to treat as string(text).

You can also do this programmatically by calling `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE` (this is a generated constant that has the value "debug" in case of a debug build)

Comment: Thanks, yes, just `if (variant.name == 'release')` works correct!